# UWP The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Style'

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In `ResourceDictionary` file I have a style and I try to add few resources to that style. Unfortunately, the member `Resources` is not recognized or is not accessible. I need keep resources explicitly within a style.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestProject.Resources">

    <Style>
        <Style.Resources> <!--Style doesn't like it here-->
```

Uwp's style seems to doesn't like it. Is there any equivalent or sufficient workaround? Or I am doing something completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`Style` does not have `Resources` property (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.style#properties-)). Controls and visual elements do. If you want to add resources, you can add them either under a control, all on the same level as the `Style` element:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestProject.Resources">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" ... />
    <Style>
        <!-- use MyBrush in this style -->
```

If you define resources on the same level as the `Style` they will be unfortunately available globally, but that is similar how the default UWP styles are defined in the default XAML resource dictionaries (`generic.xaml`).

Comment: That's what I thought. In this case I'll hard-code some of them or move to different dictionary resources or make keys more specific and put them on global level.